# Matplotlib - contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am struggling a bit with contour plot in matplotlib. I've read through the instructions and example but can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

I have x, y, z data. The data is basically as follows:

```
x    y    z
1.1  2.1  0
0.9  3.2  1
2.6  4.1  0
3.1  1.1  1
0.3  0.9  1
...
```

It is a long list of x-y coordinates and at each point it is a 0-1. The use case is balls(1), strikes(0) crossing the strikezone in baseball. When I plot the data using plt.hexbin you see the following:

[image: strikezone image]

What I want to do is to plot a contour at the 50% line. Like this imagine below:

[image: 50% contour plot]

I was hoping to use contour but I am unclear how I can get the data is a sufficient format to draw the contour plot and use 'levels' to plot just the 50% contour. Apparently the function `contour(X,Y,Z)` requires 2-D arrays so based on the data I have I am unclear on what exactly I need to do.

Is there a way I can put the data I have into a function to get the contour plot I want, like with hexbin?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a meshgrid from your x and y data:

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(data[:,0], data[:,1])
```

Then you can interpolate the z grid:

```
# Choose one option
# Z = griddata((data[:,0], data[:,1]), data[:,2], (X, Y), method='nearest')
 Z = griddata((data[:,0], data[:,1]), data[:,2], (X, Y), method='linear')
# Z = griddata((data[:,0], data[:,1]), data[:,2], (X, Y), method='cubic')
```

And plot the data using contour with the specified level at 0.5:

```
levels = 0.5
contour(X,Y,Z,levels)
```

Let me know if this approach worked out for you.

Comment: Super - that is very clear and helpful answer. I will try it now.

Comment: I made a small edit to align with your variable names.

Comment: Sorry - one clarifying question. Can you explain the `func(...)`  line. I assume this is my own bespoke function to do the interpolation across the z-grid rather than a standard python function

Comment: Sorry Axel ... can you clarify what `data` is? Is this the actual data I want to plot i.e., the mean of Z in my example

Comment: I removed the func line. It should be enough to create a tuple for the griddata function.

Comment: data would in your case be a nx3 array that holds your data.

Comment: Super - got it. Works beautifully

Comment: Happy I could help you. Have a nice day!